# Change UIPickerView's component height?

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a pickerView whose height is 28, I want each component to be of the same height of the pickerView, so I return 28 in `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent` but this doesn't seem to work. if I returned 10 instead of 28, the height changes. Is there a imitation on the maximum height which can be returned in `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent`, like if it exceeded a certain threshold it uses a default height?

Comment: Try increasing the height one by one form 10 and see where it stops working.

Comment: What if I want my row component to take the full height of the pickerView, do you know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Elsewhere on SO, I found that picker view has specific height sizes (162.0, 180.0 or 216.0), but can't find that in Apple documentation. I'd guess that, along with picker view height, the number of rows displayed both above and below the selector row would determine the max size of a single row.  Plus, each row does seem to diminish in height the further it is away from the selector bar.